# Why executing system command with pipeline in Java fail without whitespaces?

Tags: java, shell, unix, runtime, pipeline

In the shell command line both commands are legit and run without a problem:

```sh
# without whitespaces
parted /dev/sdd print free -m|grep free
```

and

```sh
# with whitespaces
parted /dev/sdd print free -m | grep free
```

However, as soon as I run from Java the former version of it (the one without white spaces), i.e.:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("parted /dev/sdd print free -m|grep free")
```

It fails:

```
2019-09-10 18:33:34.012  WARN 2528 --- [           main] Utils      : Error running parted /dev/sdd print free -m|grep free: parted: invalid option -- '|'
parted: invalid option -- 'g'
parted: invalid option -- 'r'
parted: invalid option -- 'e'
parted: invalid option -- 'p'
Usage: parted [-hlmsv] [-a<align>] [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]]...]
```

However, the same java line with the latter command version (the one with whitespaces) runs perfectly fine.
Obviously `'|'`-symbol doesn't get recognized when run from Java. The question is why?

Comment: Start by making use of `ProcessBuilder`.  If this is a system command, you may need to execute it via a shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules used by the Java `exec` function are not the rules used by the shell.

`exec` [splits into tokens based on whitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)).

thus `foo|bar` is a single token.
Shell parsing, by contrast, will treat it as 3 separate elements, `foo`, `|`, and `bar`.  The man pages for bash spell out bash processing for you in great detail.

Comment: That explains why that happens: it goes through the "single" token "m|grep" and considers it as a set of options and so it processes each letter as a separate option starting from 'm' which it knows, but fails on "|", obviously not knowing this option. Great answer, thanks!